# Unable to change value in config.php

Tags: magento2, module, magento2-cloud, enable-disable

I have a Magento Cloud server. In which I need to disable a Module. From my local environment, I have changed the app/etc/config.php "My_Module" => 0.

And committed the changes. But my changes not moved to the cloud server.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What versions of ece-tools and Magento do you use?

Comment: Try to run the module status command to check either your module exists if not then try with the upgrade and run compile too then check.

Comment: It might be your changes not affected in cloud server ka...Try yo pull your code and check whether your code if affected ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue due to Disk Space not enough to run the deploy on Cloud Server. Hence we couldn't disable the module.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running the `php bin/magento module:disable` command in a local checkout of your code to ensure that the proper module name is used as it is possible it is not matching approrpiately.  This will add the `MyCompany_MyModule => 0` to the config.php.  After that, git add/commit the updated config.php and it should be disabled!

Answer (score 0):

**Try to disable using command line**
**command :-** php bin/magento module:disable My_Module

Comment: Tried the same in local environment. We can't run this comment in Cloud server.